# How to extract column names properly?

Tags: r

I would like to extract the column names after some data manipulation:

data:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-09-04"), as.Date("2015-09-13"), by = "days")
b<-c(1000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
c<-c(10,11,12,13,14,15,15,1,18,1000)
d<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
e<-seq(5,14,1)
df<-data.frame(dates,b,c,d,e)
```

here I would like to use a function for outlier detection [anomaly detection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series):

```
tsoutliers <- function(x,plot=FALSE)
{
  x <- as.ts(x)
  if(frequency(x)>1)
    resid <- stl(x,s.window="periodic",robust=TRUE)$time.series[,3]
  else
  {
    tt <- 1:length(x)
    resid <- residuals(loess(x ~ tt))
  }
  resid.q <- quantile(resid,prob=c(0.25,0.75))
  iqr <- diff(resid.q)
  limits <- resid.q + 1.5*iqr*c(-1,1)
  score <- abs(pmin((resid-limits[1])/iqr,0) + pmax((resid - limits[2])/iqr,0))
  if(plot)
  {
    plot(x)
    x2 <- ts(rep(NA,length(x)))
    x2[score>0] <- x[score>0]
    tsp(x2) <- tsp(x)
    points(x2,pch=19,col="red")
    return(invisible(score))
  }
  else
    return(score)
}





data<-lapply(df[,2:5],tsoutliers )

names(data)
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

here I use the

```
library(stringi)
```

in order to have the opportunity to bind lists with differing rows:

```
res <- as.data.frame((stri_list2matrix(data)))
res

                  V1                V2 V3                V4
1  15178354561080816                0  0                 0
2  33856330254037544                0  0                 0
3   4033168544496767                0  0                 0
4                  0                0  0                 0
5                  0                0  0                 0
6                  0                0  0                 0
7                  0                0  0                 0
8                  0 4.47011310645824  0                 0
9                  0 76.7919635157679  0                 0
10                 0 32.7413708467736  0 0.409090909090909
```

rename columns

```
colnames(res) <- unique(unlist(sapply(data, names)))
```

Comment: The previous answer, `colnames(res) <- names(data)` still works. I still can't reproduce the error that you mentioned.

Comment: what is the question here? can you post the exact last step and the error you are getting and the expected output?

Comment: Prior to the edit of this post, there was a report that renaming the columns of `res` according to the names in `data` results in an error. I pointed out that the error couldn't be reproduce with the given example, so the post was changed.

Comment: @ RHertel. You suggested `colnames(res) <- names(unlist(data))` which results in `names' attribute [503026] must be the same length as the vector [1002]` `colnames(res) <- names(data)` works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: This was my first answer, which worked for your example. However, I edited the answer before you edited the post as I realized that `unlist()` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with

```
colnames(res) <- unique(names(data))
#> res
#      b     c   d   e
#1 105.4 110.9 0.4 9.5
```

(...although `unique()` is not necessary in this example).

Comment: Thx for that suggestion. I have already used that approach and had error `'names' attribute [503026] must be the same length as the vector [1002]` Therefore I decided to use `colnames(res) <- unique(unlist(sapply(data, names)))` where I get nor error but numbers

Comment: With your example I cannot reproduce the error. What is the output of `length(names(data))` and `ncol(res)`?

Comment: Yes I just realized hat. Do you mind if I adjust the example by the function I`m using?

Comment: Of course not; go ahead, I'll delete this answer and then we'll see if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you lose the names when converting list to matrix and then to dataframe.
Sounds simpler to just concatenate vectors within list into a dataframe:

```
do.call(cbind,data)
              b         c d         e
1  1.517835e+16  0.000000 0 0.0000000
2  3.385633e+16  0.000000 0 0.0000000
3  4.033169e+15  0.000000 0 0.0000000
4  0.000000e+00  0.000000 0 0.0000000
5  0.000000e+00  0.000000 0 0.0000000
6  0.000000e+00  0.000000 0 0.0000000
7  0.000000e+00  0.000000 0 0.0000000
8  0.000000e+00  4.470113 0 0.0000000
9  0.000000e+00 76.791964 0 0.0000000
10 0.000000e+00 32.741371 0 0.4090909
```

Comment: Thats a great solution. It seems to be the right format. However, I'll get also a `Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 13)`

Comment: I could not reproduce that warning with the data provided. Perhaps, somewhere in the bigger dataset you get different numbers of rows. It would help a lot if you provide the data that causes that error. Also, it seems like your function just throws away NA's if there are any in the data, for example `length(tsoutliers(c(1000, 2, NA, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)))` gives 9, whereas the length of the vector provided is 10. This means that it will completely mess up data structure if it meets any NA's in the original data